# Computed observable function in knockout

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have a problem with my knockout implementation. I am new to knockout so would appreciate the help.

I have the following code:

```
    function updateViewModel() {
        if (typeof groupId == 'undefined') {
            groupId = getDefaultGroupId();
        }

        $.getJSON("api/livestatusgroup/children/" + groupId)
            .done(function (data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, liveStatusViewModel.groups);
                groupsLoaded();
            });

        $.getJSON("api/livestatusgroup/resources/" + groupId)
            .done(function(data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, liveStatusViewModel.resources);
                resourcesLoaded();
            });

        this.resourceImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
            return "../Image/" + this.ResID;
        }, this);
    }


    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.resources = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
        self.groups = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
    }

    var vm = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Unfortunately, the computed observable function resourceImagePath is not correctly capturing the ResID for my resource, so I end up with urls like /Image/undefined.

What am I missing? I have checked and the ResID field definitely exists in the view model.

S

Comment: 1. It's not clear, how do you call `updateViewModel()` function (what object `this` refers to?). 2. Anyway your `computed` wouldn't work whis way, because it's not subscribed to `ResID`, regardles is it `observable` or not.

Comment: So, please show us full code of model, containing ResID, and the code where you call `updateViewModel()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement a `ko.computed` observable, it only creates a dependency for observables that are referenced within the computed function.  Remember that observables must be referenced by executing them, because they are functions - it's this action that allows the computed function to detect and track a dependency.

Otherwise, the computed function will only be able to use the value that is available at the time the computed function is first executed.

This code references `this.ResID`, but doesn't have any dependency on it due to not treating ResID as an observable.

```
 this.resourceImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
        return "../Image/" + this.ResID;
    }, this);
```

Try ensuring that `this.ResID` is, in fact, an observable, and add parentheses like this:

```
 this.resourceImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
        return "../Image/" + this.ResID();
    }, this);
```

Comment: So how do I make ResID observable? It is part of my view model.

Comment: I don't know exactly what all your code looks like, but I assume that ResID is coming from the server and getting added to your view model via the mapping plugin.  If that's the case, may need to manually map the data result into observable fields that are pre-defined on your view model `this.resId = ko.observable()`, or you may need to configure the mapping plugin to create observables on your behalf.

Comment: I'd really like to just use this.ResID = ko.observable(), but I'm not sure where to put this or what should go in the brackets! I tried putting it in the LiveStatusViewModel() constructor with no effect, probably because I'm missing the stuff in the brackets. Yes you are right, I am getting the view model with the mapping plugin.